# « He raised a United States flag on the ships's mast... » : (faire) (se) hisser ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, syntaxe, formulation-idiomatique, verbes-pronominaux

> Perhaps recognizing his crew was outgunned, the Catalpa's American
> captain hatched a clever plan. He [**raised**](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/raise) a United States flag **on the
> ships's [mast](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/mast)** and, according to an exhibit in Canberra's National
> Museum of Australia, bellowed these words: "That's the American flag.
> I am on the high seas, my flag protects me. If you fire on this ship,
> you fire on the American flag." - [*The Catalpa Rescue: The story behind one of Australia's most incredible prison escapes*](https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/catalpa-rescue-escape-australia-perth/index.html) (CNN)

Au TLFi on a une référence à *hisser le drapeau* avec un exemple : « [Faire] amener le pavillon tricolore et hisser l'Union Jack (De Gaulle) ». Est-ce que ce sont des gens ou des bâtiments qui hissent des pavillons etc. ?

J'ai une hésitation, c'est [*hisser*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hisser) ou *(faire) (se) hisser*, ou les deux ou autrement ; en quoi ça diffère ou non de *[battre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/battre/1) pavillon* ; l'emploi le plus cohérent est-il pronominal, réfléchi ? Si on avait à traduire « He raised a United States flag on the ships's mast... » comment s'y prendrait-on et pourquoi ?

Comment: Si le pavillon représente le drapeau britannique : « Il hissa le pavillon en haut du mat, car le bateau battait pavillon Anglais »  « Il hissa le drapeau en haut du mat/de la hampe, car le bâtiment (l'immeuble) appartenait à des Anglais ». C'est un cérémonial exécuté à la main.

Comment: http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/14189/battre-pavillon/

Comment: @Personne Donc mon hésitation ne serait pas justifiée...

Comment: … en effet. Notez aussi qu'un gros navire peut être appelé *bâtiment* dans "La Royale" (et par d'autres flottes), nom donné à la marine de guerre du temps de Louis XIV, sur lequel  perdure encore un monde à part qui forme ses recrues sur un trois mats et donc conserve les traditions maritimes passées, dont le vocabulaire de l'époque où il n'y avait pas de drapeau à bord, mais des pavillons. Comme on s'est bien bagarré des deux côtés de la Manche par canonnières interposées, je suppose que la Marine anglaise à de semblable traditions :-)

Comment: @Personne J'employais _bâtiment_ dans le sens naval dans la question. Je faisais justement allusion à un emploi par métonymie ou à des idées comme avec _battre pavillon_, où comme le mentionne TLFi, le pavillon est objet de battre (le bâtiment arbore...) et sujet à la fois (battre au vent) ; un truc avec le procès de l'action. La réponse opte plutôt simplement pour la logique de la hiéarchie de commandement.

Answer (score 2):

*Cette réponse reprend certaines informations données par @Personne en commentaire.*

Selon moi, la meilleure traduction pour cet extrait est :

> Il hissa le pavillon des États-Unis sur le mât du bateau [...]

Cela ne veut pas forcément dire qu'il l'a fait lui-même (cela peut être un membre de son équipage), mais étant donné qu'il en est le responsable, le capitaine est le sujet de la phrase.

Si l'on voulait insister sur le fait qu'il n'a pas hissé le pavillon lui-même, on pourrait employer la construction "faire hisser": "*Il fit hisser le pavillon [...]"*.

La forme pronominale seule n'est pas adaptée ici, car ["se hisser"](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_hisser/40052) signifierait que le pavillon exécute cette action lui-même, ce qui est bien sûr impossible.

La forme "faire se hisser" serait grammaticalement correcte (*"Il fit se hisser le pavillon"*), mais inutilement compliquée dans ce contexte. Par ailleurs, cette construction donne l'impression que le pavillon se hisse lui-même, mais que le capitaine l'a aidé/incité à le faire.

Enfin, l'expression "[battre pavillon](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/14189/battre-pavillon/)" signifie "naviguer sous le drapeau d'un pays" et ne fait pas référence à l'action de changer le pavillon. C'est donc inadapté pour traduire la phrase d'origine. Voici un exemple qui aide à distinguer les deux expressions :

> Il hissa le pavillon des États-Unis sur le mât du bateau. À présent qu'il battait pavillon américain, le navire serait à l'abri d'une attaque.

Comment: Merci ! D'accord _faire se hisser_ est compliqué mais pas « absurde », on n'est pas convaincu : _Il fit se remplir un verre d'eau par l'unique pouvoir de sa pensée_ rappelle une [scène](https://youtu.be/si1lgFFpj8E) entre Dr Strange et Thor avec le bock de bière...

Comment: Oui en effet, et ça confirme ma suggestion selon laquelle cette forme renvoie une idée de chose qui se fait d'elle-même, sous l'impulsion du sujet de la phrase. C'est un bon exemple, je vais tempérer ma réponse sur l'absurdité :)